# Is there no in-built msbuild task to concatenate and optionally minify multiple js files?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I am developing a web application in Visual Studio. its all client side code and i am writing in typescript. I created a number of `ts` files. As part of build process i want all the generated `js` files to get concatenated into one so that the html page has to download only one `js` file that contains all the source code. In addition a developer wants following configurable switches:

- a debug build in which js files are not minified
- a retail build in which js files are minified

Doing a search I can sort of see [tools](https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AjaxMinTask) to do this but looks like visual studio projects still have no inbuilt capability for this. is that true? what i want is that visual studio allows me to configure what files i want concatenated into a js bundle and further to control whether the bundle has to be minified or not depending on whether its a debug or release build. looks like there is no easy inbuilt way to do it, is that correct? i read typescript has modules. if a module spans multiple ts files, does typescript generate a js file per ts file? any way to make typescript consolidate all js files belonging to a module into one?

Comment: I am not sure why you expect VS has built-in functionality for a task that is quite far ayway from it's core business.. Sure it's an IDE, but it cannot contain *everything*. Anyway the page you linked to does exactly what you want. So unless somebody wrote an extension to deal with it from within VS: no, there is no built-in way. But the page has detailed info on how to do it,and for different things depending on configuration, use MsBuild conditions (aka `Condition="$(Configuration)=Debug"`) etc. It's really not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are developing in ts, you can concatenate all the js files into one by using the `<TypeScriptOutFile>` tag in your csproj like this:

```
<TypeScriptOutFile>app.js</TypeScriptOutFile>
```

using this tag is equivalent to using `--out` option with `tsc.exe`. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15864631/147530) answer provides the mapping between `tsc.exe` options and equivalent tags to use in a `csproj` file. Note that the ts compiler relies on the `<reference>` tags in `ts` files to determine the order in which the generated `js` classes should appear in the final output file. if that order is incorrect, you will run into errors like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24420500/147530) one.