# Ionic2: Runtime Error Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic2 and am getting this error:

> ```
> Runtime Error
> Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
> ```

Reading [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-when-extends-in-typescript/53869/8) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420500/typescript-error-runtime-error-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-wh), it suggests it could be related to the order in which a subclass and baseclass are declared.  I am using a baseclass with a subclass. Where do you change the order in which they are declared, is it in the imports? In what file?

Funny thing is my code was working fine, and suddenly started to get this error, even without me changing the base or sub classes. I did make a change to another file, which I have now reverted, but still get the error.

More details:

**Error:**

> ```
> main.js:24046Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>     at __extends (main.js:24046)
>     at job.ts:26
>     at Object.<anonymous> (job.ts:24)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cdd11c2…:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:46012)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cdd11c2…:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (personModel.ts:21)
>     at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap cdd11c2…:19)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (locationModel.ts:11)
> ```

Code:

**job.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, InfiniteScroll, Content, Platform, Events, AlertController, LoadingController, ViewController, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { JobModel } from '../model/jobModel';
import { PersonModel } from '../model/personModel';
import { SubCategoryModel } from '../model/subCategoryModel';
import { LocationModel } from '../model/locationModel';
import { RatingModel } from '../model/ratingModel';
import { ReviewPage } from '../review/review';
import { ChatsPage } from '../chats/chats';
import { CategoryPage } from '../category/category';
import { PersonPage } from '../person/person';
import { MyCameraPage } from '../mycamera/mycamera';
import { JobService } from '../service/jobService';
import { PersonService } from '../service/personService';
import { RatingService } from '../service/ratingService';
import { UtilityService } from '../utils/utilityService';
import { SearchJobsParent } from '../searchjobs/searchjobsParent';
import { MapRangeService } from '../service/mapRangeService';

@Component({
  selector: 'job',
  templateUrl: 'job.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class JobPage extends SearchJobsParent {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
.....
```

**searchJobsParent.ts**

```
...
@Component({
})
export class SearchJobsParent {
...
```

**ionic info**

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI:  You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
6.4.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: If I extend the base class, then I get the error. If I don't extend it, then the error goes away. How are you supposed to extend objects then?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using Composition instead of Inheritance.

You create an instance of the class you have the common functionality in:

**myClas.ts**

```
private someCommonClass: SomeCommonClass = null;
    ...
    this.someCommonClass = new SomeCommonClass(platform, ref);
```

**someCommonClass.ts**

```
constructor(platform: Platform)
```

Comment: I think, it's just a workaround but we should find the way to use abstraction in typescript...

Comment: I have the same issue, but i don't fine the way to use typescript abstraction. any idea please?

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you solve this issue? may be small code snippet?

Comment: Do not use an `extends SomeClass`. But rather import `SomeClass` and call `this.someClass.someFunction();`

Comment: Do I need to inject it into the `constructor` of the `subclass` or what?

Comment: I have added an update to the answer above. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh ... we have to do everything inside the sub class's constructor no?

Comment: still the same error.this is how I did.Hope I'm wrong? `export class 
Page1 {
  abstractPage: AbstractPage = null;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.abstractPage = new AbstractPage(1, true);
    }`

Comment: what is `ref` here `this.someCommonClass = new SomeCommonClass(platform, ref);` ?

Comment: It seems we cannot use your method also no? Or Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The very first comment [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21) got me thinking right and led me to a solution. My problem was I was trying to import a class into my base class. The imported class wasn't being bundled in the right order. By switching the order of my import statements in app.component.ts I was able to solve the problem.

In app.component.ts:

**Wrong**

```
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { LoginPage } from "../pages/login/login";
```

This was wrong because ListPage extended AppPage (not listed here) which imported LoginPage.

**Right**

```
import { LoginPage } from "../pages/login/login";    
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem happen because you install Native plugin and this plugin extends from IonicNativePlugin for Example (Base64ToGallery, TextToSpeech, ...). So, this caused in conflict, Iremoved this extends  and it is work...

Following this steps for Example to TextToSpeech Plugin:

1. in this Path `YourProjectFolder\node_modules\@ionic-native\text-to-speech`
2. open file `index.d.ts`
3. go to declaration to class:

   ```
   export declare class TextToSpeech  extends IonicNativePlugin{
   /**
    * This function speaks
    * @param options {string | TTSOptions} Text to speak or TTSOptions
    * @return {Promise<any>} Returns a promise that resolves when the speaking finishes
    */
   speak(options: string | TTSOptions): Promise<any>;
   /**
    * Stop any current TTS playback
    * @return {Promise<any>}
    */
   stop(): Promise<any>;
   }
   ```
4. Delete `extends IonicNativePlugin` and save.

That is all!

Answer (score 0):

Did anybody try to provide a reference file with the correct order like this:

```
/// <reference path='SomeCommonClass.ts' />
/// <reference path='TheExtendingClass.ts' />
```